# Exporting Dependabot as JSON

Tags: json, github, dependabot

Anyone know how one can export Dependabot findings in GitHub as JSON? I've seen this done before, however can't seem to find anything online about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the vulnerabilityAlerts for xx/yy in the following way:

```
gh api graphql -F owner='xx' -F name='yy' -f query='
  query($name: String!, $owner: String!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
        vulnerabilityAlerts(first: 100) {
            nodes {
                createdAt
                dismissedAt
                securityVulnerability {
                    package {
                        name
                    }
                    advisory {
                        description
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
'
```